# Paste colums of a dataframe and then "View" them

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I am trying to paste two columns of a dataframe and then look at the resulting character vector using "View" function but I get this error:

> "Error in View : 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]"

Here is my reproducible example:

```
name1 <- c("A2015169","A2015177","A2015185","A2015193","A2015201","A2015209","A2015217","A2015225",
           "A2015233","A2015241","A2015249","A2000049","A2000057","A2000065","A2000073","A2000081",
           "A2000089","A2000097","A2000105","A2000113","A2000121","A2000129","A2000137","A2000145",
           "A2000153","A2000161","A2000169")

name2 <- c("h07v06","h07v06","h07v06","h07v06","h07v06","h07v06","h07v06","h07v06","h07v06","h07v06",
           "h07v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06",
           "h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06","h08v06")

df <- data.frame(name1,name2)

names <- paste(df$name1,df$name2,sep=".")

View(names)
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Maybe quit using RStudio?

Comment: Your example did not produce that error for me, I viewed it fine. Heads up though be careful in naming your datasets such common words as names. It just so happens `names()` is a base function. ( I even did it in R Studio ;) )

Comment: I get the same error - regardless of naming of the `names` object.

Comment: Saw similar behavior in RStudio 0.99.xyz, rolled back to 0.98.abc and it's gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your suggestions. I was using RStudio version 0.99.485 with R-3.2.2. Frank, I used the same R version (3.2.2) without RStudio and this time it worked. Honey Dipped Badger, thank you for the suggestion, I changed the name of variable "names" and still did not work in RStudio 0.99.485. Alexey Ferapontov, I used the same version of R with RStudio 0.98.1103 and it worked this time! This said, it seems like the problem was the RStudio version. I believe this answers the question but I do not want to take the credit for the answer, I think Frank and Alexey Ferapontov deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no problem that related to the version of R.

The result that you mention in the code is a type of **list** we cannot view list type data using `View()` .

The `View()` is only used for the dataframe.

For Example

```
x = letters
y = seq(1:26)
z = data.frame(x,y)
View(z)
```